# Selenium can't find chromedriver.exe

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core

We're upgrading to .NET Core, and we have a crawling engine that uses Selenium for some tasks. We use `chromedriver.exe` and it works just fine in .NET 4.6.1.

For .NET Core, we created a console application, and added these packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="3.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="3.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="2.34.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I run my code, I get this error:

> The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or
>   in a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be
>   downloaded at http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

I can see that after build, `chromedriver.exe` is getting copied to `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` folder. I also copied it manually to `bin\Debug` folder. But in both cases it can't be found.

What do I miss here?

Comment: What directory is it looking for the driver in? It says `current directory` but what directory is that? Is it the same one where the exe is located?

Comment: @tehbeardedone, this is a pretty standard .NET Core console application, really a bare-bone application. You can create it in less than 30 seconds via Console template and adding those packages and writing a line of code to instantiate `ChromeDriver` and run it. That's it. I have no idea where **current directory** refers to. I guess its `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0`

Comment: I would hazard a guess at Selenium not being fully cross platform compatible. Unless it somehow bundles and exe with the nuget package because (I'm guessing) you're building on Windows

Comment: @JamieTaylor, the thing is, in nuget is says that it supports .NET Standard 2.0. I have no idea. How that can be tested?

Comment: Looking at the source for `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver` (https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/blob/master/buildTools/download-driver.ps1) it looks like it should be downloading the correct version of Chromium for your platform. If you search for `chromedriver`, what do you get and where does it live? I feel like this is related to the comment by @tehbeardedone about the `current directory`

Comment: Ha, I just got it to work after tinkering with it during my lunch break. Look for my answer in a few. I have no idea why it works this way but it does.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't explain why it works this way but this is how I got it to work.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
```

I initially copied the driver into the same directory as my `Program.cs` and passed in the path to the driver like so:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("chromedriver.exe");
```

That resulted in this message:

> The file chromedriver.exe\chromedriver.exe does not exist.

So just for kicks I tried passing in `"."` for the path and it worked.

This is probably a better solution. The driver needs to be in the same directory as your app code. Not in the `/bin` directory and this will work.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

Comment: And if you don't have the chromedriver.exe file, you can download it from here: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: It works because the argument that you're providing is the directory containing `chromedriver.exe`, not the path to `chromedriver.exe` (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs#L93).  It definitely threw me for a loop too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and i have fixed it by this way.

First find the version of your Chrome.

Help-> About Google Chrome. There you will find your version number.

then copy URL provided below and place your current Chrome version number into those inverted comma, Then hit Enter. It will directly redirect you to latest download.

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=" "/ (full URL)
Download Zip, Extract it and implement.