# when using chromedriver, with specflow, a new browser instance open per step

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

I'm having an issue with Specflow. For some reason, a new instance of chrome is started per step. 
can you help with this?

For follow test, 3 steps, 3 chrome instance are started.

```
Feature: Home

Background: 
Given The  QA Department site

Scenario: QA Department title 
    When QA site open
    Then QA site tile must be "UI Testing Site"
```

The first instance has the content i want but the other two, that i don´t know why are started, are empty.

```
namespace QAtests.SpecFlow_Steps.Home
{


     using NUnit.Framework;
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Text;
     using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

    [Binding]
     class HomeTestSteps
    {
        private readonly MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
        private readonly PageHelper pageHelper = new PageHelper();

        public HomeTestSteps()
        {

        }

        [When(@"QA Department site open")]
        public void GivenQADepartmentSiteOpen()
        {
            var url = this.mainPage.ValiteSiteAddress();
            Assert.AreEqual(url, this.mainPage.siteURL);
        }


        [Then(@"QA Department site tile must be ""(.*)""")]
        public void ThenQADepartmentSiteTileMustBe(string pageTile)
        {
            var title = this.pageHelper.GetElementTitle();
            Assert.AreEqual(pageTile, title);
        }

    }
}
```

The main page class just sets the url and checks elements

```
namespace QAtests.Pages.Main
{
    public class MainPage
    {

        private ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        private readonly string elementTitle = "//title";
        public readonly string siteURL = "http://uitest.duodecadits.com/";

        public MainPage()
        {

        }


        public void StartSite()
        {
            try
            {
                this.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(siteURL);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Can´t set address.", e);
            }

        }

        public void Close()
        {
            this.driver.Close();
        }

        public string ValiteSiteAddress()
        {
            return this.driver.Url;
        }

        public IWebElement ElementTitleisVisible()
        {
            try
            {
                return this.driver.FindElement(By.XPath(elementTitle));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw new Exception("Element tile not found.", e);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I think that is related with the declaration of

```
private ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a new ChromeDriver instance each time you instantiate a page.

As suggested, you will want to setup your webdriver in a `BeforeScenario` step.

Also, you could make use of the built in IOC container and register your web driver instance. Then that instance can be injected into any of your page objects, as and when they are needed.

Something like...

```
[Binding]
public class BaseScenarioHooks
{
    protected IObjectContainer Container;

    public BaseScenarioHooks(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    [BeforeScenario(Order = 3)]
    public void SetupDrivers()
    {
        var webDriver = new WebDriver(browser, seleniumHub, url, Context.ScenarioInfo.Title,
            Context["UniqueTestName"].ToString(), FrameworkConfiguration.VideoRecording);

        Container.RegisterInstanceAs<WebDriver>(webDriver);
    }
}
```

Have a look at https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection.

Also have a look [here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/blob/master/SeleniumGridWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/Drivers/WebDriver.cs) for ideas on how to organize your driver class

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing your thread get a lot of love here. In all honesty, I would look for a SpecFlow framework online and then start building yours out from there. SpecFlow uses hooks so you are probably going to want to invoke your browser with a BeforeScenario so that it is called once for each test. Put your cleanup in an AfterScenario hook.

If you use the nuget chromedriver and have it set always output to your bin debug folder, you can use the GetBasePath call so it always calls from that directory. You can remove the call and hard code the chromedrive.exe path though. This just makes it easier if it is going into source control.

Hopefully this will help you get started.

ex.

MyFile.cs

```
  [BeforeScenario]
  public static void Startup()
  {
  Browser.StartWebDriver();

  }
```

Browser.cs

```
 public class Browser
 {
    static IWebDriver _Driver;
    static WebDriverWait _wait;

  public static void StartWebDriver()
  {
                ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.Combine(GetBasePath, @"bin\Debug\"));
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
                options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
                _Driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);
                _wait = new WebDriverWait(_Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));


  }




    public static string GetBasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath =
                System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName((System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
            basePath = basePath.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 10);
            return basePath;
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This line

```
private ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

is definitely your problem.  Every time you access this property you are creating a new driver.

Here's a web hook class i use in my tests.

```
[Binding]
internal sealed class WebHooks
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

    public WebHooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeScenario("web")]
    public void BeforeWebScenario()
    {
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");

        //HACK: this fixes issue with not being able to find chromedriver.exe
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910244/selenium-cant-find-chromedriver-exe
        var webDriver = new ChromeDriver(".", options);
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

        _objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<IWebDriver>(webDriver);
    }

    [AfterScenario("web")]
    public void AfterWebScenario()
    {
        var webDriver = _objectContainer.Resolve<IWebDriver>();

        if (webDriver == null) return;

        webDriver.Close();
        webDriver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

So this registers the webdriver with the internal SpecFlow DI container so that it can now be called in you step definitions.

Then modify your step definition class to access the webdriver as a constructor parameter

```
[Binding]
public class YourSteps
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _webDriver;

    public CanvasSteps(IWebDriver webDriver)
    {
        _webDriver = webDriver;
    }
}
```

Specflow's internal DI automagically wires everything up and you should now have 1 webdriver instance per scenario.  It also creates a better design because your cross-cutting concern of a webdriver instance has been extracted from your steps and placed in a [Hook](https://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/) where is belongs.  Just tag your scenario with the @web hook