# I want to execute multiple scenarios in a single SpecFlow feature file one after another (based on selenium) but it's not working and showing an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, specflow

I am new to SpecFlow and working a POC so that I can use the VisualStudio+SpecFlow+Selenium combo in my project. I created a Feature file and added two Scenarios. First for Login and Second for a page creation. So I'll login with one user and will create a page in the same session. I generated the step definition file from the feature file using SpecFlow. Below is my Feature file content:

```
Feature: Login and create page configuration page
    This feature will test the login and the page configuration page creation functionality:

@Login
Scenario Outline: Login into Minerva Cloud
    Given User open up the "<URL>"
    When User login using "<UserName>" and "<Password>"
    Then User successfully logged into the Minerva Cloud
    And User selects the "<ClientName>"

Examples: 
|URL|UserName|Password|ClientName|
|https://####|####|####|## Global Services|


@PageConfigurationPageCreation
Scenario Outline: New Page Configuration page creation
    Given User click on the new button
    When User enters details like "<Name>" "<Type>" "<CRMtype>" "<URL>" "<Description>" "<AccessGroup>" in the creation page
    And click on the Save button
    Then the new page is created

Examples: 
|Name|Type|CRMtype|URL|Description|AccessGroup|
|PageConfiguration_Sunil1|CRM|Vertex|URL|Description for my Page|Access Group to be selected|
```

The generated step file snippet is attached:

[Code Generated by SpecFlow and i added the required Selenium code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzOIz.png)

So whenever I am running the feature file, it executes the login scenario without any issue but it fails as soon as it reaches to the 2nd `Given` statement (marked with red in the image attached) which belongs to the 2nd Scenario and throws an error. The error is:

**System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Looks like it's somehow losing the current instance of the Webdriver which i initialised in the first scenario.

Please help!

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Include the coded as plain text in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ChromeDriver across SpecFlow Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409700/using-chromedriver-across-specflow-tests)

Comment: Sure, will take care of it in future. And no, i haven't found any answer for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want single instance of driver for all the scenarios in a feature, then initialize your driver in [Beforefeature] and dispose it using [Afterfeature], like below

```
namespcae Yourproject
[Binding]
public class BeforeAndAfterFeature
{
[BeforeFeature]
    public static void InitializeDriver()
    {
        //Place your driver initialize code here
    }
[AfterFeature]
    public static void QuitDriver()
    {
        //Dispose driver object
    }
}
```

2. Or if you want to open and quit browser for each and every scenario, use [BeforeScenario] and [AfterScenario] tags

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your driver inside the 1st `Given` method.  That means it will die after that scenario is run.  I don't use SpecFlow but from a quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886258/when-using-chromedriver-with-specflow-a-new-browser-instance-open-per-step) it looks like you need to use a `[BeforeScenario]` to initialize your driver and an `[AfterScenario]` to close it

Comment: Thanks for your reply mate but if i close the driver after the first scenario then i'll end up in the same situation which i am in right now. I mean it doesn't solve the purpose of executing both the scenarios one after another as i want to execute the login scenario first and creation scenario right after the first one. I want to do it because i want to achieve "Login once and validate multiple" scenario. I hope it provides some sort of clarification.

Comment: the idea is to use `[BeforeScenario]` one time before any of your scenarios execute and `[AfterScenario]` one time after the last scenario executes.  So you would be initializing it once and wouldn't be closing it until the end after all scenarios run

Comment: I may be wrong but i far as i could check, these hooks executes automatically as soon as the Scenario starts. If there is a way to control them please let me know. I would like to give it a try.

Comment: We have [BeforeFeature] and [AfterFeature] as well so i was thinking to use them but looks like [BeforeFeature[ and [AfterFeature] is not working for me. Not sure why. Tried Context Injection as well but still as soon as the 2nd `Given` starts, it invokes the webdriver again.